# Call Python function within a Bash Script

Tags: python, bash

I have a Python file called `data.py` that looks like this:

```
import json 

def txtToJson(textfile):
    #rest of the code

def jsontToTxt(jsonfile):
    #rest of the code
```

I am also given a `run.sh` file to call each function from the Python file. I have tried doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = '-s' ]
then
    if [ "$2" = '-j' ]
    then
        ##Serialize JSON
        python -c "import data; print(data.txtToJson($3))"
    fi    

elif [ "$1" = '-d' ]
then
    if [ "$2" = '-j' ]
    then
        ##Deserialize JSON
        python -c "import data; print(data.jsonToText($3))"
    fi
fi
```

However when I try running the script I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'`. How can I get the `run.sh` to call the different Python functions properly?

Comment: Where is `data.py` located relative to `run.sh`, and relative to the directory from which you call `run.sh`?

Comment: use argparse module to define command line arguments (flags) for your script and in your bash script just write down something like `python data.py --file=/path/to/file --text_to_json`

Comment: @mkrieger1 run.sh and data.py are in the same directory

Comment: And what about the second part of my question?

Comment: But what's the current directory when you run `run.sh`? Do you run it like `./run.sh` or e.g. `./some-dir/run.sh`?

Comment: @steinar I run it like ./run.sh.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I dont really understand your second part. I have a folder and in that folder both data.py and run.sh are saved there

Comment: The second part of the question was: where is `data.py` located relative to the directory from which you call `run.sh` - in other words: from which directory do you call `run.sh`? Apparently it is in the same directory, so if you run `ls` you should see both `data.py` and `run.sh`, correct?

Comment: Could you change your `run.sh` script temporarily to only run the following: `ls ; python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`, and give us the output of running `run.sh` in exactly the same way as you have before?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes that is correct

Comment: Are there any other files or subdirectories?

Comment: @steinar that gives `['', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/encrypt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Sentinelone-0.1-py3.7.egg']`

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes there are a few other files but they dont pertain to the `data.py` or `run.sh` files at all. The other sub directories are created from Pycharm such as `__pycache__`, `bin`, `include` and `lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you've provided, I think you must be running from another directory than where these files are, i.e. that the current directory is different than the one containing `run.sh`. If that's correct, adding the following at the top of your script should help:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
cd $DIR

...rest of bash file...
```

This will change the current directory to the directory where the bash file resides.

Comment: More can be read about this (rather unreadable) piece of bash code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/282024